# Getting a binary string and convert it to decimal

Tags: arduino-nano

I have a 4 dipswitch to get a 1 or a 0, try to get that into a string and from that get a decimal, therefor if I get for example a 0011 a 3.

so, I know that from the variations of 0000 to 1111 is a decimal from 0 to 15, I already have my string but how do I convert the "binary string" to decimal?

to get the string I'm using this (the I is at 5because there is where is the dipswitch):

```
      for(int i = 5; i <= 9; i++){    
           Serial.println(digitalRead(i));
           Dstate = Dstate + digitalRead(i);
      }
```

Comment: What has a String got to do with anything?

Answer (score 1):

What you want are the bit-shifting operators << and >>, and the OR operator |:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    Serial.println(digitalRead(5 + i));
    Dstate = Dstate | (digitalRead(5 + i) << i);
}
```

You'll notice I changed the loop so it runs from 0 to 3 instead of 5 to 9 - it makes other parts easier if you start counting from 0.

Then the line:

```
Dstate = Dstate | (digitalRead(5 + i) << i);
```

is where all the magic happens.  Let's break it down:

```
digitalRead(5 + i)
```

That of course gives you a 0 or 1 for pins 5, 6, 7 and 8 in turn.

```
<< i
```

That shifts the value returned by `digitalRead()` left `i` bits.  For instance, if `digitalRead()` returns 1 and `i` is 0 then `1` is left shifted 0 times so remains as 0b0001.  If `i` is 1 then it left shifts one bit, so the value becomes `0b0010`.  If `i` is 2 then it shifts two bits, so you get `0b0100`.

Finally the result is combined with the current value of `Dstate` with OR, so the four values basically get laid over the top of each other.

So say you have the four switches in the positions ON-OFF-ON-OFF and `Dstate` starts off as 0, then the sequence would be:

```
i = 0, digitalRead = 1, shifted = 0b0001, OR = 0b0001
i = 1, digitalRead = 0, shifted = 0b0000, OR = 0b0001
i = 2, digitalRead = 1, shifted = 0b0100, OR = 0b0101
i = 3, digitalRead = 0, shifted = 0b0000, OR = 0b0101
```

Comment: awesome response, but then how do I change the value 0b0101 to decimal and get a number from 1 to 15?  because if I try 0b0101 in a binary to decimal calculator from google, it obviously won't work

Comment: It already is a number from 0 to 15.

Comment: yeah you are right! I messed up when I copied and pasted your code and then started playing with the dipswitches to notice the change.